# Migrating a question from a beta SE

Tags: support, migration, beta-phase

I have posted a question on [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5372/using-edge-detection-for-classification). But now i feel its more suitable for [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) and want it to be migrated,i came to know about cross-validated later. But since datascience is beta, not a lot users have enough points to migrate. What should i do in that case to get the answers? Deleting a question again might be counted as a negative contribution.

Comment: Flag it. Moderators can move a question to any site. (until it gets 60 days old)

Comment: From the dupe faq: *You can also flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you. Simply explain in the reason which site you want it to be migrated (please select one site; don't list all possible sites it could go to)*